# Получаю [object Object] вместо данных в React SSR

Tags: reactjs, ssr

Имеется сервер. При ReactDOMServer.renderToNodeStream(jsx) хочу получить свой сайт и данные, которые были отправлены с бэкэнда на фронтенд. В итоге получаю фронтенд и [object Object] вместо данных. Как это можно решить?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/lemitooo/blog-client/-/tree/main - gitlab c кодом